# Django Rest Framework - two models in the same api call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to do a thing with Django Rest Framework. 
I've a class that is linked to another class via foreign key.
now, i want to create an API call create both the models.

```
class A(models.Model):
     text = models.CharField(...)
...


class B(models.Model):
...
      myfield= models.ForeignKey(A)
```

that's fine.

```
class SerializerForB(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    text = serializers.CharField()
....
```

that's also fine (i've meta etc setted up). if i go to the URL of the API i see the form with all the fields of B plus the one to put the text for A.

then i wrote this view

```
class BCreate(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SerializerForB


def pre_save(self, obj):
    b = B(text=self.request.DATA['text'])
    b.save()
    obj.B=b
```

the probelm is with the actuall save of A and the fact that data has the field `text` it says

```
'text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

should i write an API for creating A and use the `pk` when i create the B via the API? or can i do both in one call?

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/task/human/create/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'general',
 'requester',
 'executor',
 'crispy_forms',
 'social_auth',
 'developer',
 'restapi',
 'requests',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'djrill',
 'mturk',
 'jsonify',
 'gravatar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  326.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  323.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  361.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  50.         if serializer.is_valid():
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
  478.         return not self.errors
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in errors
  470.                 ret = self.from_native(data, files)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in from_native
  866.         instance = super(ModelSerializer, self).from_native(data, files)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in from_native
  323.             return self.restore_object(attrs, instance=getattr(self, 'object', None))
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in restore_object
  851.             instance = self.opts.model(**attrs)
File "/Users/stefanotranquillini/.virtualenvs/CC/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  415.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/task/human/create/
Exception Value: 'reward_quantity' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: It would be worth including the traceback for the exception in this question.

Comment: there's the traceback, not that reward_quantity is the text of the example. as you can see the problem is the same.

Comment: Your issue is that `reward_quantity` isn't a field on the model.

Comment: so i can't do what i've in mind, right?

Answer (score 0):

The model class 'B' is raising the exception you're seeing, when you try to instantiate it with `B(text=self.request.DATA['text'])`, presumably the model class `B` doesn't have a `text` field.

Comment: the model have it. i'll do some more testing, but i'm pretty sure it has the field and that the complain is with the auto-seriazliation of A. i'll check it.